# ng-transclude inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe

I am trying to make a printing directive using AngularJS but I got stuck on something. I am trying to write an HTML and on the parent div, I'm trying to call a directive to transclude the content inside an iframe, so I can call print on the entire iframe.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="print-frame">
  <h1>Print Title</h1>
  <p>Print Text comes here...</p>
</div>
```

and the directive that tries to transclude this content into an iframe looks like this:

```
myApp.directive('printFrame', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    template: '<iframe><!doctype html><html><body ng-transclude></body></html></iframe>',
    link: function(scope, elem) {
      elem.bind('click', function() {
        alert('clicked!');
      });
    }
  }
});
```

But when I try an iframe, nothing happens, it doesn't show anything inside the iframe's `<body>` tag. Here is a jsfiddle where I use a div and an iframe and the div works but not the iframe.
http://jsfiddle.net/zjFp4/545/

Comment: You can't treat the inside of an iframe window as if it was html in the main page. Concept won't work. You are dealing with completely separate windows and angular doesn't even exist inside the frame window